# Linked Service connection timeout

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm attempting to configure a Linked Service within my Data Factory. In this case, it's to a MariaDB instance on Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

I'm able to establish the connection from other parts of the virtual network just fine (ex. Windows 10 VM + HeidiSQL). However, when I attempt to configure (ip, database, credentials) and test the connection, I get:

```
ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][MariaDB] (1004) The connection has timed out while connecting to server: ip_here at port: 3306. Activity ID: omitted.
```

The storage account and the data factory are using the same subscription and resource group as the Ubuntu instance. The storage account is configured for All Networks.

**Edit 1**

I used the generic MariaDB option to setup the linked service.

**Edit 2**

Found this tidbit...

" [...] Azure Data Factory Azure Integration Runtime is not inside a VNET so by default it cannot connect to your Azure SQL Database. [...] the best you can do is to whitelist the IP Ranges for Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime [...]

**Edit 3**

Tutorial on how to setup an integration runtime:
https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2018/07/03/how-to-get-azure-data-factory-connecting-to-your-data-on-a-vnet-or-internal-network/

However, seems this is only available on Windows (and I'm on Linux)?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using "Azure Database for MySQL" and was able to have the Data Factory communicate to it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a similar ask on  [Microsoft Q&A Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/9378835a-0206-4b52-890e-12a397824b17/azure-data-factory-integration-runtime-for-linux-box?forum=azureiothub)

> Today the self-hosted Integration Runtime is only supported on Windows
> machine. However, what you can do is to run self-hosted Integration
> Runtime on a separate Windows machine that has network connectivity to
> the Linux machine where the data files reside.

If you are flexible to use other databases, you can use for example a Azure Database for MySQL as @TekiusFanatikus has successfully used.